# How to sum a property from each element in an ObservableCollection Based on a filter property on each element?

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactive, reactiveui, dynamic-data

I'm working on a system that has a list of Records displayed in a list.

Each item has the following properties:

- Name
- Id
- Size
- A Boolean indicating if this item should be included or not - ShouldBeIncluded

A user can check a checkbox to change the boolean of the item from false to true. etc.

Based on a user changing various item's checkboxes I need to keep a "TotalSize" **property up to date** so that it reflects the sum of all item's size property in the list where the item's "ShouldBeIncluded" property is true.

I'm trying to do this within a UI based app running ReactiveUI/Dynamic Data.

**I use an MVVM approach in everything else I do. So I'm not looking for tieing this code directly to my view layer.**

For the purposes of this question I've minimised this all down to a simple reproduction though.

I think I need to Observe property changes on the ObservableCollection but I cannot figure out how to then bind this back to the ReactiveUI property.

- I've tried various DynamicData methods, including the ones I've commented out.
- I've tried ObservableAsAProperty helpers
- I've tried doing this manually

But I want to understand the most Idiomatic way to do this, but everything I'm trying to do seems to overcomplicate it.

Here's some boilerplate code that shows where I'm at:

```cs
using DynamicData;
using DynamicData.Binding;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1;
/** Simplified for this question, but let's say I'm building a UI with this layout
 * | Name    | Should be Included| Size |
 * | Record 1| [ ]               |5     |
 * | Record 2| [ ]               |5     |
 * ... etc.
 * 
 * Total: the sum of items' size where their "Should be included" checkbox is true
 */


// For some boilerplate code here we go

// Our "Record" which has the properties from the table above
public class Record : ReactiveObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Reactive]
    public int Size { get; set; } = 0;

    [Reactive]
    public bool ShouldBeIncluded { get; set; } = false;

    public Record(string id, string name, int size)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Size = size;
    }
}

// A "View Model" that can be used to display them
public class Test
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> records;

    // How do I keep Total up to date with the correct value, in this case 15?
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();

        //records.ToObservableChangeSet(x => x.Id).Filter(x=> x.ShouldBeIncluded). What's next? Is this right?;
    }

}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new test object
        var t = new Test();

        // Add 10 records to it, each with a size of 5
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            t.records.Add(new Record(i.ToString(), $"Record {i}", 5));
        }

        // Mark 3 records as needing to be "Included"
        t.records[0].ShouldBeIncluded = true;
        t.records[3].ShouldBeIncluded = true;
        t.records[5].ShouldBeIncluded = true;

        Debug.Assert(t.Total == 15);
    }
}
```

You can also find a minimal reproduction Avalonia app on GH: https://github.com/ProbablePrime/Repro-ReactiveUI-MVVM-Sum-Filter

Comment: `public int Total => records.Where(r => r.ShouldBeIncluded).Select(r => r.Size).Sum();`

Comment: That won't be kept up to date, with changes in the collection by my understanding.

Comment: So you don't need a propfull, a readonly property is sufficient

Comment: No, I need it to be up to date and in sync with the state of the collection. Your solution just calculates it on access. I need it to always be up to date so it can be bound to UI and stay up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this same question over on the Avalonia discussions board.

A user named: alxgenov

[Provided a DynamicData based answer](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/10978#discussioncomment-5586001) that works perfectly!

```cs
private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> total;
public int Total => total.Value;

// In constructor
total = Records
    .ToObservableChangeSet(x => x.Id) 
    .AutoRefresh(x => x.ShouldBeIncluded)
    .Filter(x => x.ShouldBeIncluded)
    .Sum(x => x.Size)
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Total);
```

This will keep Total up to date as an ObservableProperty that Avalonia can bind to.

Thank you all for your help!

You can see this implemented in the example app here: https://github.com/ProbablePrime/Repro-ReactiveUI-MVVM-Sum-Filter/commit/55d1042e52a5da6f773e0dc37f099226e27b9829

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing this from the UI, you can request de calculation of `TotalSize` and `NotifyPropertyChanged(TotalSize)`.

If you want to do it by changes on the boolean, your model should implement  `NotifyProperyChanged` in the setter of the Property.

Anyhow, your code is not calculating TotalSize (As noted by your Debug.Assert). I would use @Pieterjan suggestion for calculating it: `public int Total => records.Where(r => r.ShouldBeIncluded).Select(r => r.Size).Sum();`

Comment: How can I request a re-calculation?

My properties in the collection do already implement INotifyChanged using the ReactiveUI Fody Weavers. (Hence [Reactive]).

What I need is to pickup a signal from any item in the observable collection to know when its ShouldBeIncluded property is changed.

PieterJan's suggestion is not Reactive, it won't Notify the UI when it changes, I can't use it.

Comment: Add Reactive to your Total Property and use a readonly (=>)

Comment: Ok, but then how do I know when I need to update it? I need to pickup a signal from the collection? How?

Comment: That is what Reactive will do for you. If you want to call it manually, call it from the CheckBox_StateChanged method/Action.

Comment: It doesn't I've updated my code to include [Reactive] on the total property and Pieter's method. I also then modify the state of one element in the collection, you can see the updated code here: https://gist.github.com/ProbablePrime/819072e465d3d1acc2e5056f9d3d74ea

Total never updates via NotifyProperty, so the UI would be stuck?

Using CheckBox_StateChanged breaks MVVM and so is not suitable.

I'll spin this up in GH as a full UI app. That might help.

Comment: I've created a Minimal Repro as an Avalonia app here: https://github.com/ProbablePrime/Repro-ReactiveUI-MVVM-Sum-Filter Thank you for looking.